# Posting comment to FB page successful but sends OAuthException error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, comments

I'm trying to pot a comment to a post on a FB page. The comment makes it to FB successfully, but I get an error as a response instead of the new comment ID.

Here's my request:

curl --data "message=testing" https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID_POSTID/comments?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

And the error:

{"error":{"message":"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.","type":"OAuthException","code":2}}

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, only just started happening yesterday. Please subscribe to the bug I've logged, and maybe we can get FBs attention: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/291521920964008